# Google cloud messaging to store mobile gcm id on login activity

Tags: android

I am trying to use google cloud messaging service to store gcm id when user login into the system but i do not how to do it on login activity.Anybody can help me with any working sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) link or [most prefered from android developers](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).
Here's another [link](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/antoine-campbell/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial) with nice tutorial about implementing google Cloud messaging

Comment: you may accept this answer as helpful so that other's may know.

Answer (score 0):

please use below function:

```
public static String registerClient(Activity activity) {
        String regId = "";
        String registrationStatus;
        try {
            // Check that the device supports GCM (should be in a try / catch)
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(activity);

            // Check the manifest to be sure this app has all the required
            // permissions.
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(activity);

            // Get the existing registration id, if it exists.
            regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(activity);

            if (regId.equals("")) {

                registrationStatus = "Registering...";

                // register this device for this project
                GCMRegistrar.register(QwichesApplication.mContext,
                        CommonVariable.GCM_PROJECTID);
                regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(activity);

                registrationStatus = "Registration Acquired";
                Log.d("tag", regId);
                // This is actually a dummy function. At this point, one
                // would send the registration id, and other identifying
                // information to your server, which should save the id
                // for use when broadcasting messages.

            } else {

                registrationStatus = "Already registered";

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            registrationStatus = e.getMessage();

        }

        Log.d("tag", regId);

        // This is part of our CHEAT. For this demo, you'll need to
        // capture this registration id so it can be used in our demo web
        // service.

        return regId;

    }
```

this function returns gcm_id .
i hope its useful to you...

Comment: Thanks dipali..actually i am trying to connect to web application and storing a gcm id in a mysql database is getting difficult as i am a very new to android and gcm as well

Comment: i think my code is helpful to you..if its really helpful then please accept this answer.